# How do you upgrade Auto Slapper?

Tags: best-fiends-forever

How do you upgrade auto slapper to level 2?

Answer (score 3):

To upgrade Auto Slapper, go into the menu at the bottom right - this will take you to a menu where you can level up your fiends and also level up their skills. Levelling up skills like Auto Slapper takes a lot more coins than leveling up the fiends, so you will have to save up for it.